# Duplication In SSRS (Subreport)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm create a SSRS report where I'm trying to create sub query with 2nd report working fine but its giving me repeat Records

see the below image anyone know where i'm wrong

[Repeating records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYBVf.png)

[Repeating records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZQuq.png)

[Report 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjOyO.png)

[Report 2 Sub report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rjjhf.png)

[Report 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXByw.png)

[Report Preview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5K1u.png)

[SubReport Parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiv0S.png)

Comment: Anyone ........?

Comment: can you show a screen shot of your RDL design layout with groupings etc..  and your dataset. I'm thinking you have your subreport at the detail level and so it is repeating for every single row returned

Comment: Please find the Attached images Thanks

Comment: When you run the subreport on it's own does it have repeating values? Or is thew problem that the same subreport is repeated? The screenshots you've posted are not of any help. I can't work out what the actual issue is

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling "Report1" from "Report2"

Your screen shot confirms my suspicion that the subreport is embedded in the details group on Report2.

All you need to do is on Report2, insert a row **outside** the detail group and add your subreport in that line and take it out of the details group.   That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm taking it that you put the sub report in the grouping level and not the detail level?